# How recursion works to get the value the first time it runs

Tags: perl, recursion

```
sub maxNum {
 if (@_ == 1) { 
    return $_[0]; # terminal clause - return immediately 
 }  
 my ($first, @rest) = @_;
 my $remainingMax = maxNum(@rest);
  if ($first > $remainingMax) { 
    return $first;
  }  
 return $remainingMax; 
}
```

I am having trouble digesting this piece of code which uses recursion. Basically i am confused by the `my $remainingMax = maxNum(@rest);` part.

i just want to know how the value for `$remainingMax` is found when the script runs for the very *first time* after which i understand that the function `maxNum(@rest)` provides a value by returning the ans (i.e.  either `return $first` or `return $remainingMax`).

Comment: How is this initially called?

Comment: Your understanding of recursion is faulty. Earlier calls to a recursive function essentially block until all later recursive calls complete.

Answer (score 5):

Recursive functions generally follow a “divide and conquer”-strategy.

To find the maximum of a list

```
max(a, b, c, d)
```

we can partition that list arbitrarily, then find the maximum of all local maxima:

```
<=> max( max(a, b), max(c, d) )
```

Your algorithm chooses the following partition:

```
<=> max( a, max(b, c, d) )
```

The same happens for `max(b, c, d)`, resulting in the following call graph:

```
max(a, b, c, d)
   max(b, c, d)
      max(c, d)
         max(d)
```

At `max(d)`, the algorithm doesn't recurse further. Instead, this is the *base case* (the equivalent to a termination condition of a loop). `max(d)` returns `d`. We can now find the total maximum by comparing the maximum of the rest of the list to our first value, working our way back through the call stack

---

There are many other ways this idea can be encoded. It could be translated to the non-recursive form

```
sub maxNum {
   my $current_max = pop;
   while(@_) {
     my $compare = pop;
     $current_max = $compare if $compare > $current_max;
   }
  return $current_max;
}
```

This compares the elements in the same order as your recursive solution.

Finding the maximum can also be considered a *folding* operation (aka `reduce`). We can write a recursive function that does the following partition:

```
    max( a, b, c, d )
<=> max( max(a, b), c, d )
<=> max( max(max(a, b), c), d )
```

This *looks* quite complex, but leads to an elegant solution:

```
sub maxNum {
  return $_[0] unless $#_;       # return if less than two elems
  my ($x, $y) = splice 0, 2, @_; # shift first two elems from @_
  my $max = $x > $y ? $x : $y;   # select larger
  return maxNum($max, @_);       # recurse
}
```

A function call whose value is immediately returned is termed a *tail call*. We can make those more efficient by using a special `goto &subroutine` expression. However, we have to set up the argument list manually:

```
sub maxNum {
  return shift unless $#_;        # base case: return on one argument
  my ($x, $y) = splice 0, 2, @_;  # take the first two elems from start
  unshift @_, $x > $y ? $x : $y;  # put the larger one back there
  goto &maxNum;                   # recurse with tail call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your confusion.

The first time `maxNum` *completes* it returns the last item of the list.

Now, if you think of the list of the last two items, when you pass those in, one becomes `$first` the other is the only element assigned to `@rest`. When you pass `@rest` as only one element, you reach the terminal condition and that element gets returned and stored in `$remainingMax`. You then compare the two last elements, and return the maximum one.

From there, if you originally called `maxNum` with a list greater than two items, you consider the max you returned and compare it with the third item from the end of the list (Perl subscript `-3`). If that was your total list, then you have your max. If not, you return that and compare it with the fourth item from the last (Perl subscript -4).

In quasi-"Perl notation"

```
maxNum( $_[-1] )     ==> $_[-1];
maxNum( $_[-2..-1] ) ==> $_[-2] > maxNum( $_[-1] )     ? $_[-2] : maxNum( $_[-1] ); 
maxNum( $_[-3..-1] ) ==> $_[-3] > maxNum( @_[-2..-1] ) ? $_[-3] : maxNum( @_[-2..-1] );
maxNum( $_[-4..-1] ) ==> $_[-4] > maxNum( @_[-3..-1] ) ? $_[-4] : maxNum( @_[-3..-1] );
...
```